# How can I use Librispeech 360h dataset in google-colab?

Tags: python, dataset, pytorch, training-data

I'm using Google colab (GPU Enabled) to train my ASR model. The accuracy of the model using the train-clean-100 Librispeech dataset is not great, so i decided to download the **train-clean-360 dataset** using : `torchaudio.datasets.LIBRISPEECH("./data", url='train-clean-360', download=True)`
But i can't download it since the disk storage available in google-colab is 36GB

I tried to upload and unzip the **train-clean-360 dataset** in my google-drive account and mount it to google-colab so I can use the dataset without downloading it with this line of code:

```
torchaudio.datasets.LIBRISPEECH("/content/gdrive/My Drive/", url="train-clean-360", folder_in_archive="LibriSpeech", download=False)
```

but it's not working.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there any other way to use this dataset in google-colab ?